# How to change button color by clicking another button from another activity permanently

Tags: android, button, colors

i have a problem 
i have button A in first activity and button B in second activity,i want when someone click button B in second activity then color of A button is change permanently it never reverse to previous colour again when ever user not uninstall the app

Comment: Use shared preference store the  status,on base   you  make change the  color of button

Comment: Please, try some code first and in case of any problems, post your tried code to get help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you ask a question in SO, you should try something first and when you hit a problem, then you can ask your question as specific you can, along with all things you have done. you can read about how you can ask a good question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Now you can try something like this:

```
//create a method in your first activity, (where the button color should change):

public void changeColorInFirstActivity(){
    Button btnA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButtonA);
    btnA.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
}
```

And add this in your second activity where you want to click on a button to change the first activity button color:

```
Button btnB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButtonB);
btnB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          FirstActivity secondActivity = new FirstActivity();
          firstActivity.changeColorInFirstActivity();
        }
});
```

Now after setting the color, save the color `int` in shared preferences and set the value you get on your button color in your First activity

Comment: add stacktrace.